# Arguments for non-automatic generation of user interfaces

Tags: user-interface, automation

I am in a software developing team and we are starting a discussion about how can we work together to get better software and software more easily to maintain.

One of the problems that we want to resolve is the dependence of some applications to the person who developed it. In some cases, the code was only implemented by one person and the code is very hard to understand and the documentation not exist or is very poor.

To resolve this problem, someone came with the idea of creating a tool for code generation. This way, all the code will be standardized and will be understand by all the team members.

The main problem is that the generation of the code include the automation for creating interfaces and the majority of the team members sees this as a very good idea. The automation of creation of the interfaces for the final user requires the definition of the ideal interface for the basic uses cases for some group of data, like create, read,  update, delete and listing (CRUD+L). The idea is to create and automatic process that will generate interfaces for a specific predefined classes of business objects. The only member that opposed to this idea was me. I think this process will resolve the problem of disparity in the code developed but will bring a bigger problem, lower software quality. They argument that the code generated could always being change, but the existence of a tool to generate automatic interfaces will not always detract the user centre design principals? This will not lead to an application that only serve to manage data instead of an application that support the uses cases?

Now I have the task to create a document to convince the team not use this type of approach for creating interfaces. What are the best arguments to persuade the team to use another process for creating applications more user friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, generated code will *always* need to be tweaked, if your primary concern is a high quality user experience. That means you will have to put a mechanism in place to manage those tweaks as your code evolves over time.

Instead of spending countless hours building some sort of code generation tool, invest in a good code review tool and then use it. Your code will get better and your team will get better.

The root problem isn't bad code, it's bad developers. Using a code generator will not fix the problem, it will only mask the symptoms.